# Maven dependency imports wrong child dependencies versions

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, build, version

I have a dependency https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.zipkin.reporter2/zipkin-sender-okhttp3/2.7.14 declared as

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>io.zipkin.reporter2</groupId>
        <artifactId>zipkin-sender-okhttp3</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.14</version>
</dependency>
```

This dependency in it's pom has parent dependency with pom file that declares dependency like this:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
    <artifactId>zipkin-reporter</artifactId>
    <version>${project.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

project.groupid equals to io.zipkin.reporter2 and project.version equals to 2.7.14. So maven should import dependency `<artifactId>zipkin-reporter</artifactId>` with version equals to 2.7.14. **BUT** it imports versions 2.2.0. I don't declare this dependency anywhere else and other dependencies don't have this dependency as transative. I tried reinstall maven, reclone project from git, invalidate cache and restart IDEA, delete .m2 folder - nothing worked.
The weird thing is that I have other project that is using the very same dependency (`<artifactId>zipkin-sender-okhttp3</artifactId>`) and all versions are in order how they should be.
Any ideas how I can fix it?

Edit: mvn dependency:tree output (I edited out sensitive info): `

```
mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose -Dincludes=io.zipkin.reporter2:zipkin-reporter
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[WARNING]
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for com.***.rnd.dep:***-deployment:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[WARNING] 'dependencies.dependency.(groupId:artifactId:type:classifier)' must be unique: commons-io:commons-io:jar -> duplicate declaration of version 2.6 @ com.***.rnd.dep:***-deployment:[unknown-version], C:\Users\nimi0218\Des
ktop\Projects\CJM(DEP)\***\***-deployment\pom.xml, line 70, column 21
[WARNING]
[WARNING] It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten the stability of your build.
[WARNING]
[WARNING] For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer support building such malformed projects.
[WARNING]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Build Order:
[INFO]
[INFO] Notification Service                                               [pom]
[INFO] ***-api                                           [jar]
[INFO] ***-impl                                          [jar]
[INFO] ***-sms                                           [jar]
[INFO] ***-email                                         [jar]
[INFO] ***-push                                          [jar]
[INFO] ***-rest                                          [jar]
[INFO] ***-mq                                            [jar]
[INFO] ***-deployment                                    [jar]
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------< com.***.rnd.dep:*** >-------------
[INFO] Building Notification Service 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT                       [1/9]
[INFO] --------------------------------[ pom ]---------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.10:tree (default-cli) @ *** ---
[WARNING] Using Maven 2 dependency tree to get verbose output, which may be inconsistent with actual Maven 3 resolution
[INFO] com.***.rnd.dep:***:pom:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] \- io.zipkin.reporter2:zipkin-sender-okhttp3:jar:2.7.14:compile
[INFO]    \- io.zipkin.reporter2:zipkin-reporter:jar:2.7.14:compile
[INFO]
[INFO] ----------< com.***.rnd.dep:***-api >-----------
[INFO] Building ***-api 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT                   [2/9]
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.10:tree (default-cli) @ ***-api ---
[WARNING] Using Maven 2 dependency tree to get verbose output, which may be inconsistent with actual Maven 3 resolution
[INFO] com.***.rnd.dep:***-api:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] \- io.zipkin.reporter2:zipkin-sender-okhttp3:jar:2.7.14:compile
[INFO]    \- io.zipkin.reporter2:zipkin-reporter:jar:2.7.14:compile
[INFO]
[INFO] ----------< com.***.rnd.dep:***-impl >----------
[INFO] Building ***-impl 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT                  [3/9]
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.10:tree (default-cli) @ ***-impl ---
[WARNING] Using Maven 2 dependency tree to get verbose output, which may be inconsistent with actual Maven 3 resolution
[INFO] com.***.rnd.dep:***-impl:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] \- io.zipkin.reporter2:zipkin-sender-okhttp3:jar:2.7.14:compile
[INFO]    \- io.zipkin.reporter2:zipkin-reporter:jar:2.7.14:compile
[INFO]
[INFO] ----------< com.***.rnd.dep:***-sms >-----------
[INFO] Building ***-sms 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT                   [4/9]
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.10:tree (default-cli) @ ***-sms ---
[WARNING] Using Maven 2 dependency tree to get verbose output, which may be inconsistent with actual Maven 3 resolution
[INFO] com.***.rnd.dep:***-sms:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] \- io.zipkin.reporter2:zipkin-sender-okhttp3:jar:2.7.14:compile
[INFO]    \- io.zipkin.reporter2:zipkin-reporter:jar:2.7.14:compile
[INFO]
[INFO] ---------< com.***.rnd.dep:***-email >----------
[INFO] Building ***-email 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT                 [5/9]
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.10:tree (default-cli) @ ***-email ---
[WARNING] Using Maven 2 dependency tree to get verbose output, which may be inconsistent with actual Maven 3 resolution
[INFO] com.***.rnd.dep:***-email:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] \- io.zipkin.reporter2:zipkin-sender-okhttp3:jar:2.7.14:compile
[INFO]    \- io.zipkin.reporter2:zipkin-reporter:jar:2.7.14:compile
[INFO]
[INFO] ----------< com.***.rnd.dep:***-push >----------
[INFO] Building ***-push 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT                  [6/9]
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.10:tree (default-cli) @ ***-push ---
[WARNING] Using Maven 2 dependency tree to get verbose output, which may be inconsistent with actual Maven 3 resolution
[INFO] com.***.rnd.dep:***-push:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] \- io.zipkin.reporter2:zipkin-sender-okhttp3:jar:2.7.14:compile
[INFO]    \- io.zipkin.reporter2:zipkin-reporter:jar:2.7.14:compile
[INFO]
[INFO] ----------< com.***.rnd.dep:***-rest >----------
[INFO] Building ***-rest 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT                  [7/9]
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.10:tree (default-cli) @ ***-rest ---
[WARNING] Using Maven 2 dependency tree to get verbose output, which may be inconsistent with actual Maven 3 resolution
[INFO] com.***.rnd.dep:***-rest:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] \- io.zipkin.reporter2:zipkin-sender-okhttp3:jar:2.7.14:compile
[INFO]    \- io.zipkin.reporter2:zipkin-reporter:jar:2.7.14:compile
[INFO]
[INFO] -----------< com.***.rnd.dep:***-mq >-----------
[INFO] Building ***-mq 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT                    [8/9]
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.10:tree (default-cli) @ ***-mq ---
[WARNING] Using Maven 2 dependency tree to get verbose output, which may be inconsistent with actual Maven 3 resolution
[INFO] com.***.rnd.dep:***-mq:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] \- io.zipkin.reporter2:zipkin-sender-okhttp3:jar:2.7.14:compile
[INFO]    \- io.zipkin.reporter2:zipkin-reporter:jar:2.7.14:compile
[INFO]
[INFO] -------< com.***.rnd.dep:***-deployment >-------
[INFO] Building ***-deployment 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT            [9/9]
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.10:tree (default-cli) @ ***-deployment ---
[WARNING] Using Maven 2 dependency tree to get verbose output, which may be inconsistent with actual Maven 3 resolution
[INFO] com.***.rnd.dep:***-deployment:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] \- io.zipkin.reporter2:zipkin-sender-okhttp3:jar:2.7.14:compile
[INFO]    \- io.zipkin.reporter2:zipkin-reporter:jar:2.2.0:compile (version managed from 2.7.14)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary for Notification Service 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT:
[INFO]
[INFO] Notification Service ............................... SUCCESS [ 22.484 s]
[INFO] ***-api ........................... SUCCESS [  1.086 s]
[INFO] ***-impl .......................... SUCCESS [  1.060 s]
[INFO] ***-sms ........................... SUCCESS [  0.790 s]
[INFO] ***-email ......................... SUCCESS [  0.960 s]
[INFO] ***-push .......................... SUCCESS [  1.112 s]
[INFO] ***-rest .......................... SUCCESS [  1.327 s]
[INFO] ***-mq ............................ SUCCESS [  0.827 s]
[INFO] ***-deployment .................... SUCCESS [  4.317 s]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  39.287 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-03-01T15:37:07+03:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

`
All modules have version 2.7.7 as they should be but one module with name  ...-deployment has versions 2.2.0. It doesn't set explicitly there.

Comment: I'm not sure, but there may be some other library which is using this versions dependency. I repeat, I'm not sure, but you can figure out if any.

Comment: Looks like your using a place holder for zipkin-reporter. see if `<project.version>` is been overridden by **another** `<project.version>` tag in `<properties>`

Comment: Please call `mvn dependency:tree` and copy the relevant part to the question (by editing it, not into the comments).

Comment: @Clover I checked, it's not there

Comment: @JFMeier edited

Answer (score 0):

You have

```
io.zipkin.reporter2:zipkin-reporter:jar:2.2.0:compile (version managed from 2.7.14)
```

This means that there is a `<dependencyManagement>` entry in your POM or your Parent POM that sets the version to `2.2.0`.

Comment: the only `<dependencyManagement>` I have is `<groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId><version>Edgware.SR1</version>` which is not affecting zipkin. The only thing I could think of is that other dependencies have in their parent or child poms `<dependencyManagement>` which are lowering zipkin's version.

Comment: Does this have scope import?

Comment: Yes, it does. Scope is `import`.

Comment: Then you have to go to that pom and look up all the dependencyManagement in there (it is imported). If you have further scope import in there, you have to repeat the process.

Comment: I have the very same `<dependencyManagement>` block in my other component which is working just fine. I'll do that but I'm almost sure that that's not the case.

Comment: I was able to solve this issue by setting direct dependency of version I need but it looks like dirty hack for me... And I tried `<exclusions>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>*</groupId>
                        <artifactId>*</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                </exclusions>` on this `dependencyManagement` dependency, didn't solve the issue

Comment: I bet you have the entry in the dependencyManagement somewhere. This it at least what the dependency plugin says.